# Should I release an NSDictionary instantiated through the form @{}?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, memory-management, reference-counting

I have the following code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"myKey" : @"myValue" };
```

Should I release `dict` using `release` or `autorelease`?
Or I do not own the object, so I should not release it myself?

Note: I use manual reference counting (ARC is disabled).

Comment: the rule is very simple, you only release if you retain or alloc/new/copy it

Comment: There is more detail explanation in [Advanced Memory management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW12 Collections Own the Objects They Contain)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you **must not** release a `NSDictionary` created with the literal syntax. The [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#id2) tells that dictionary literal expressions expand to `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:]`, so you do not own the object.

No Objective-C literal expands to an expression creating an owning reference.

Comment: Best answer for me since link to official documentation has been provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Even if you have ARC disabled (which you should have it enabled), you do not need to release it because you do not own the object. You only own the object when you created it through `alloc` or `new`.

Comment: I added a note to my question re. ARC (disabled). Thanks you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

I asked the question too early, sorry. But here's the answer:

I tried analyzing it myself, since I cannot find references (maybe because of the vague keyword `@{}`).

When adding `autorelease` to the dictionary created by `@{ @"myKey" : @"myValue" }`, the app crashes.  I also ran the code through Xcode's Static Analyzer, and it gave a Memory issue.
So, we **do not need to release** objects retrieved using `@{}`, similar to `NSString` from `@""`.

I also tried it for `NSArray` using `@[]`. The same behavior applies.
We do not need to release them ourselves.